# what kind of encoding is this? does anyone know?

Tags: decode, encode

Does anyone know what this kind of encoding is called? and how can it be decoded?

```
7b22 6669 6c65 7322 3a7b 2270 6163 6b61
6765 2e6a 736f 6e22 3a7b 2273 697a 6522
3a31 3436 332c 226f 6666 7365 7422 3a22
3022 7d2c 2264 6973 7422 3a7b 2266 696c
6573 223a 7b22 656c 6563 7472 6f6e 223a
7b22 6669 6c65 7322 3a7b 2261 7574 682e
6874 6d6c 223a 7b22 7369 7a65 223a 3337
3731 2c22 6f66 6673 6574 223a 2231 3436
```

Comment: Looks like `ASCII`. For instance, the 1st line is `{"files":{"packa`

Comment: @JosefZ And on which site were you able to decode it?

Comment: Where the data come from? Hexadecimal dump of a file? Just open the file in your preferred code editor…

Answer (score 1):

> {"files":{"package.json":{"size":1463,"offset":"0"},"dist":{"files":{"electron":{"files":{"auth.html":{"size":3771,"offset":"146

A plain text `json` spelled as `hex` out of `ASCII strict 7bit` presented in 2 byte grouping